# When i start my newly installed machine with Ubuntu 23.04 my BIOS appears?

Tags: boot, bios

My BIOS pops up and i have to choose an unknown device from my BIOS-menu to start up Ubuntu 23.04 how can i solve this i am too scared to do anything to the BIOS because if does something in there my computer may not boot-up?

Comment: just changing BIOS settings doesn't cause issues with booting to BIOS. At the very worst, you can boot into BIOS again and change them back. You may be confusing this with *updating* the BIOS, which can, rarely, cause problems with booting if things go wrong.

Comment: Regardless, the solution to this would be to change BIOS settings to make your Ubuntu drive the priority boot drive. I had a laptop that required you to "add a UEFI file as trusted for booting." It depends on exactly what your BIOS needs. But don't be afraid, at worst you can reset your BIOS to defaults (what it is now if you haven't changed anything yourself) and all will be good.